# My header is shifting if the content below if content gets below 500px in height

Tags: html, css

I've got a multiple page website that uses the same header on every page. Im php including the header. On all but one page, the header sits in the same spot, however, on only one of the pages, the header moves about 5px to the right. I've been troubleshooting it and I've found that if I set the     div tag below it a min height of 500px, then the menu shifts back into place. As soon as the height gets below 500px, however, it moves 5px to the right again. I have identified my problem, but I do not know whats causing it or how to fix it.

I didn't see a lot of posts on stackoverflow specific to my issue, but a couple that seemed to have relevence were [Blueprint CSS: Page moves to left side if the content is long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503221/blueprint-css-page-moves-to-left-side-if-the-content-is-long) and [My Header is moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353972/my-header-is-moving) however none of the answers seemed viable to work for me. The first link suggested:

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However that did not work for me.

The second link involved it happening on different browsers, however, this is happening in the same browser.

I've also read [Why am I getting shift around header regions in two HTML pages built using almost same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866619/why-am-i-getting-shift-around-header-regions-in-two-html-pages-built-using-almos) however it didn't offer a solution for my problem either.

Here's my basic code structure. This is pretty much the same code on all pages, but each page differs in the amount of content it has under the header.

```
<div class="body2">
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="view-design-portfolio"><div>
<h2>Design</h2><br><img src="images/designheader.jpg">
</div></a>
<a href="construction-gallery"><div>
<h2>Construction Management</h2><br><img src="images/constructionheader.jpg">
</div></a>
<a href="home-staging-gallery"><div>
<h2>Home Staging</h2><br><img src="images/stagingheader.jpg">
</div></a>
</div>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</div>
```

My header and menu css below. I did not build the menu using standard html `<nav>` elements because the menu was being split up differently at first and I never went back, however, it still works fine on all but the one page. The css is included in a external file and does not change page to page.

```
.header_wrap {
height:100%;
max-height: 155px;

}

.menuli {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 49.33px;
float: left;
}

.logo {

margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 132px;
width: 400px;
}

.menui {

margin-top: 104px;

}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size: 1.17em;
}
```

Here's my header html:

```
<div class="header_wrap" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
<div class="menu-wrap">
<nav class="menu">

<!---- Menu Options Here ----->

<ul class="gmenu" style="max-width: 1088px; width: 100%; margin-top: -5px; padding-left: 0px; margin-left: 55px; color: black;">
    <li class="menuli menui"><a href="index">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="menuli menui"><a href="design">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li class="menuli menui" style="padding-right: 44.33pox;"><a href="staging">STAGING</a></li>

    <li class="menuli logo"><a href="index"><img src="images/logo.png" style="max-width: 400px !important; width: 400px; margin-bottom: 24px;"></a>   </li>  

    <li class="menuli menui"><a href="gallery">GALLERY</a></li>    
    <li class="menuli menui"><a href="shop">SHOP</a></li>
    <li class="menuli menui" style="padding-right: 0px !important;"><a href="blog">BLOG</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like some pointers on what could cause this issue and how I might go about fixing it.

Here's the link to the site: http://davisdesignandhost.com/ginger

The specific page in question is the shop page.

Comment: I don't see any shift of the header on the shop page compared to the other pages on the site.

Comment: Its pretty minimal. I had to put a thin piece of paper with the edge of the paper on the edge of the crest of the logo to see it. It really isn't enough to bother me, however, its enough to bother my client. @spencerlarry

Comment: Do what I do, check the source code around the header, chances are some orphan code has stuck around the start of the header. Helped me a lot of times. It maybe a single character from the php.